# Create table columns by *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend

I try to make table in Angular. How can I create table columns by e.g `*ngFor`?

I have lists

```
Data [  
​0: 
data: [  
0: 0
1: 4
2: 4
3: 3
4: 5
5: 1
​​​]
id: 49
label: "Label_1"
​​
1: 
data:[ 
0: 5
1: 0
2: 1
3: 5
4: 0
5: 0
​​​]
id: 50
label: "label_2"

]

---- SECOND ARRAY-----

Array [  
0: "value_"
1: "value_"
2: "value_"
3: "value_"
4: "value_"
5: "value_"
]
```

and I'd like to recieve this:

```
|   #   |   label_1    |   label_2  |   label_3  |
--------------------------------------------------
|Value1 |       1      |     4      |     7      |        
|Value2 |       2      |     5      |     8      |
|Value3 |       3      |     6      |     9      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Data will be appended to the "array", and I wish these columns were created automatically. I click button 'add data to array' and a new column is created. It does not necessarily have to be `ngFor`. Could someone help me do something like this?

Comment: Are you sure the "numbers" are like that? Not like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` ?

Comment: Sorry, it is [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] - Edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to do it is to have a table like this in HTML:

```
<table border="1">

  <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th *ngFor="let column of array">
      {{column}}
    </th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of values; index as i">
      <td>{{row}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let column of array; index as j">
        {{numbers[j][i]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

First `ngFor` is for columns, 2nd is for rows and the third is for values

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lnwxnf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update**

With new data format:

```
<table border="1">

  <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th *ngFor="let column of array">
      {{column.name}}
    </th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of values; index as i">
      <td>{{row}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let column of array; index as j">
        {{array[j].numbers[i]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nvyyc9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update 2nd**

To make fields editable use `ngModel` like this:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="array[j].numbers[i]">
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msp5ps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Many thanks for you solution ! But I'm very sorry I gave the wrong  data :( I just did the edits, could you have a look and adjust the program to the updated data?

Comment: @mat373 No problem, I updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It doesn;t works for me :( I'm again update my post and chenged data. This is my console.log response from arrays. I sit on it all day; (

Comment: @mat373 Please fork the latest Stackblitz and add your data to it, then share the link.

Comment: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4txbhi?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Stackblitz code works... but in my application as at IMAGE

Comment: Try to paste sample code from this [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead).

Comment: Doesn't works :( It's only problem with {{column.name}} it shows - "undefined". Code works but why i have there undefined ? When I try to read {{column..}} i have no hints to set "name", only push, map etc, typical methods for arrays..

Comment: Instead of `{{column.name}}` try for debug purpose this `{{ column | json }}` what you get?

Comment: Application crashed

Comment: When we want to get data[] we have temp_dataset[j].data[i], maybe it need tamp_dataset[i].name ?

Comment: Have you got any error? Can you share on Stackblitz the real data you are using?

Comment: Oh maan i'am sooo stupid xD. I'm trying with column.name but in my App it have to be columne.label. I am sorry for my stupidity and thank you very much for your time. Works perfectly. You helped me a lot !!!! Poland greets Hungary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234237/discussion-between-mat373-and-robert).